Laravel can no longer find my self-created commands
no matter what command I want to execute, Laravel responds with the following error:
There are no commands defined in the "dev" namespace.
It doesn't matter which of my commands I run. I always get the same error message, just with a different namespace
Thats my code of one command:
<?php

namespace App\Console\Commands;

use Illuminate\Console\Command;

class dTest extends Command
{
    /**
     * The name and signature of the console command.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $signature = 'dev:test';

    /**
     * The console command description.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $description = 'Command description';

    /**
     * Execute the console command.
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        $this->info("Test Command");
    }
}


My PHP-Version: 8.2.20
My Laravel-Version: 11.8.0
My OS: Debian
My Webserver: Apache
Does anyone have an idea where the error might be?
I created a new command for testing. This was done with the command
php artisan make:command --command=dev:test

Look in bootstrap/app.php to see which implementation is substituted for Illuminate\Contracts\Console\Kernel::class. (The default is App\Console\Kernel::class) Show what you have written in this contract implementation

run this command and try again: php artisan cache:clear & php artisan optimize

that is my bootstrap/app.php:
<?php

use App\Providers\AppServiceProvider;
//use Illuminate\Foundation\Application;
use Gecche\Multidomain\Foundation\Application;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Configuration\Exceptions;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Configuration\Middleware;

return Application::configure(basePath: dirname(__DIR__))
->withProviders()
->withRouting(
    web: __DIR__."/../routes/web.php",
    // api: __DIR__."/../routes/api.php",
    commands: __DIR__."/../routes/console.php",
    channels: __DIR__."/../routes/channels.php",
    health: "/up",
)
->withMiddleware(function (Middleware $middleware) {
    $middleware->redirectGuestsTo(fn () => route("login"));
    $middleware->redirectUsersTo(\App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider::HOME);

    $middleware->throttleApi();

    $middleware->replaceInGroup("web", \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidateCsrfToken::class, \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class);
})
->withExceptions(function (Exceptions $exceptions) {
    //
})->create();

The two console Commands Not worked for me. Thank you for the answers.
Crocodile202405
